# Get Text from web with Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have the following HTML structure:

```html
<div class="sub-title">
                        <span class="ng-binding">יתרת עו"ש</span>
```

I want to get the string יתרת עו"ש

I tried:

```
var Header = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class=ng-binding]"); 
Console.WriteLine(Header.ToString());
```

but I got a `NullReferenceException`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here.

1. When you are querying for an attribute, you need to use quotes around the attribute value (either single or double quotes should work).  So your code should be:

   ```
   var Header = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='ng-binding']");
   ```
2. `SelectNodes` returns either an `HtmlNodeCollection` containing one or more `HtmlNodes`, or null if the search did not find a match.  If you're only expecting one value, you need to use an index of `0` to get the first one.  From there you need to use `.InnerText` to get the text value from the node.  So your code should be:

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(Header?[0].InnerText);
   ```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMS1Dg

Comment: Thank you i wish if there is a tutorial to understand the attributes and syntax

Comment: what if i want to load from web not a string

Comment: If you want to load HTML from the web you can do: `var web = new HtmlWeb(); var doc = web.Load(url);`.  Or you can use an [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) to download the content as a string.